# chosen jQuery not working

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I have searched but not got proper answer. Finally here.

i am using jQuery chosen function to make my select box more attractive. But in vain.
please help me to fix that problem. No change is made though i have done changes in my coding.

code is here....

```
Group Assignment<select name="assigned_group" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple class="chzn-select">
<?php foreach($this->userGroupsInArray as $groups): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $groups->id; ?>"><?php echo $groups->title; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".chzn-select").chosen(); 
});
</script>
```

i have included these js and css. i have tested, they have been properly included.

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$js_path = JURI::base().'components/com_itcs_forms/js/';

$cssPath = JURI::base().'components/com_itcs_forms/css/';
$doc->addStyleSheet($cssPath.'chosen.css');
$doc->addStyleSheet($cssPath.'chosen.min.css');
$doc->addScript($js_path.'chosen.jquery.js');
$doc->addScript($js_path.'chosen.jquery.min.js');
$doc->addScript($js_path.'chosen.proto.js');
$doc->addScript($js_path.'jquery-1.6.2.js');
```

thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: So, what is the issue you are trying to fix?

Comment: it is showing as normal multiple select box. Not the stylish one. So i want to make that changes to make the select dropdown stylish...

Comment: Ah, also I have just seen Joomla in the question tags. *Runs away*

Comment: Why are you including both the normal and minified versions of the Chosen plugin?

Comment: yes, i am using joomla for coding. but i think, it is independent of any cms...

Comment: actually i have downloaded all the files from the for make that changes. i have attached all the files the website providing.

Comment: i have now commented out all the minified versions of js and css. This time also, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the jquery no-conflict framework, either in your script or your template...

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```